# Changing default 'Sorry, you don't have the rights to view this page' for private Telescope

Tags: meteor, telescope

I have set up a Telescope app (fresh install) and have set it to private. I need to change the default template that is rendered (on the homepage) when Telescope is set to private and the user is not logged in.

I have looked through the routes and client/views templates and JS files and I can not figure out how to change the template that gets rendered when a Telescope installation is set to private.

Comment: did you mean if the user is not loged in don't render the home page?

Comment: @Ethan -I have Telescope set to 'Private'. If the user is not logged in it currently shows the default "Sorry, you don't have the rights to view this page." .. I'd like to change the text with a custom Template.

Comment: Well i never see the telescope app but you can create a template inside the client/views folder an name it customTemplate and call it whatever they call the "sorry you don't have" message, did you have a place where i can see the telescope code? is [this](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change to a custom template, but you don't want to mess with the actual code.

You can just change the template content [here](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/bbf9fb9666cf07299c29e4e96d5fc37474bec1cc/client/views/errors/no_rights.html) and put whatever code you like.

Just be sure to update the [en.i18n.json](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/bbf9fb9666cf07299c29e4e96d5fc37474bec1cc/i18n/en.i18n.json) file line 131

Answer (score 0):

*When a site is set to private, users get redirected to the no_rights template (no_rights.html).*

Solved, with some help ;-) I hope others find this just as useful.